# Unable to set a conditional breakpoint checking for null

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Dim ds As DataSet = myObj.GetData() ' Returns a DataSet or Nothing
dropDown1.DataSource = ds
```

Tried to set a breakpoint on the second line that just breaks if `ds` is `Nothing`.

> The following breakpoint cannot be set:
>
> when 'If (ds IsNot Nothing)' is true
>
> First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type.

I don't really 'get' what the error means. You can assign `Nothing` to a `DataSet` and it'll compile just fine, is that not nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition doesn't need an 'If'.
It should work by selecting the 'Is true' option and entering your condition as a valid expression:

```
ds Is Nothing
```